# Not able to scroll to the bottom of the page when sticky header's position changed to fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with Menu at some distance from top. When scrolling the window if the menu reaches top I am changing the header position to fixed

```
.f-nav{ z-index: 999; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var top = $('.sticky').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= top) {
      $('.sticky').addClass("f-nav");
    } else {
      $('.sticky').removeClass("f-nav");
    }
});
```

But in certain pages when the we are scrolling down and menu reaches top, page is automatically scrolling up a bit again. So I am not able to go to the bottom of the page.I do not understand this problem at all.

Comment: Can you provide an example website to better help you in solving this problem?

Comment: what's the css for .sticky ?

Comment: sticky is the class for the header